# Finding a word a line in a file

Tags: command-line, files

Is there a command I can use to find a certain word in a file? I tried using the `find` command without any success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep. `grep` will be your friend here.

Simply do something like this:

```
cat file.txt | grep wordtomatch
```

Comment: Or just `grep wordtomatch file.txt` ;)

Comment: [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) - also, strictly speaking, grep matches *basic regular expressions* by default; to avoid surprises (in case `wordtomatch` contains regex special characters) it might be safer to add the `-F` (`--fixed-strings`) option

Comment: And if you **really** wanted to catch all the fish, you'd use `grep -i word_to_find filename` so that you'd match both upper and lower case letters.